# Magento: Reading attribute

Tags: php, magento, logical-operators

I have added a new attribute for labels in Magento and modified the file labels.phtml. If the attribute is set to YES in the backend and the item is a sale item, I want to display a different label. The code is the following, but I am not getting any result:

```
  if (($isSale == true) && ($product->getAttributeText('Clearance') == YES))
    {
     $html .= '<span class="sticker-wrapper top-right"><span 
                class="sticker sale">' . $this->__('Clearance') . '</span>        
             </span>';
      }
```

Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: When you say "not getting any result" Do you mean that it's throwing a error? Is it simply not showing a label anymore? Or is the old label still showing? - Also, might want to wrap the YES in your if clause to `'YES'`

Comment: I wrapped the 'Yes' and it is showing correctly on the test website but not on the production one?!? Code is identical and so is attribute config..Any idea why?

Comment: Not sure, but might be a issue of lowercase / uppercase ? Also, tried Maksym's answer?

Comment: code above works fine after wrapping 'Yes' on one server but not on the other. Could it be a file permission issue?

Comment: Perhaps, It's worth trying to change

Answer (score 1):

Magento stores yes/no values as 1/0.
Try to change your condition:

```
  if (($isSale == true) && ($product->getAttributeText('Clearance') == "YES"))
```

to

```
  if (($isSale == true) && ($product->getAttributeText('Clearance') === "1"))
```